# How to use PreparedStatement with JDBC

Tags: java, jdbc

I'm new to JDBC and Java.

I'm coming from Javascript and Typescript background. I decided to learn JDBC with Oracle by creating a small basic project.

I'm using `JDK 8`. I'm following this study material: [TutorialsPoint-PreparedStatement](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jdbc/jdbc-statements.htm). I figured out that problem is with my *DataService*.

Here's my `DataService` class:

```
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class DataService {
    Connection con;
    PreparedStatement pstmt;

    static String branch_name="";
    static LocalDate branch_created_on;
    static String branch_pulled_from="";

    DataService() {
        try {
            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
            con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe","system","scott");
        }
        catch(Exception e){ 
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }

    public void getValue() {
        branch_name=AddNewBranchRecord.branchNameTextField.getText();
        branch_created_on=AddNewBranchRecord.datePicker1.getValue();
        branch_pulled_from=(String) AddNewBranchRecord.combo_box_1.getValue();
    }

    public void putValue() {
        System.out.println("Branch name: "+branch_name);
        System.out.println("Branch created on: "+branch_created_on);
        System.out.println("Branch pulled from: "+branch_pulled_from);
    }

    public void insertRecord() {
        System.out.println("Adding a record...");
        getValue();
        try {
            String sql;
            sql = "insert into mybranches values (branch_name, branch_created_on, branch_pulled_from);";
            pstmt = con.prepareStatement(sql);
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(DataService.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        pstmt .close();
    }
}
```

I'm sure there's something that I missed out.

I'm not getting any error or exception but no row is inserted in the database.

I cross checked with `select * from mybranches`.

However, the same code works perfectly if I use the normal `Statement`.

Comment: Your insert statement is not valid SQL.  What are you trying to do here?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, So there won't be any datatypes in this query ? Please correct me.

Comment: I tried fixing the query. Please check it. And also, If the query is wrong, then why it is not showing any exception.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but: **Never** use the `SYS` or `SYSTEM` accounts for your regular work and never create your own tables, view or other objects in those schemas. Never.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You create the `PreparedStatement` but you don't use it.

A prepared statement is there to e.g. insert different values into a table multiple times.

You create the `PreparedStatement` once like you would execute a normal Statement and include `?` instead of the values that differ.

If you want to execute it, you have to set the values (the `?`s will be replaced with them) by using the `setXXX(int,Type)` methods and then execute it with `.execute()`.

As pointed out in the comments of the question, the SQL code is not valid. The sql code prepared statement is just like the sql code of a regular statement but the values that change all the time are replaced by `?`.

The SQL code of the prepared statement would be something like that:

```
INSERT INTO mybranches VALUES (?,?,?)
```

If you want to use the `PreparedStatement`, you could set the values like that:

```
pstmt.setString(1,branch_name);
pstmt.setObject(2,branch_created_from);
pstmt.setString(3,branch_pulled_from);
```

Finally, execute it with

```
pstmt.execute();
```

Note that (as I already said) you should create the `PreparedStatement` once and not every time you execute the `insertRecord()` method and in that method, you should just call the `setXXX` methods and the `execute()` method.

The `PreparedStatement` (and the `Connection` object) should be closed when you don't need it anymore.

Also, as @[TT.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/243373/tt) suggests in the comments, you should specify the columns in an `INSERT` statement. It would be something like

```
INSERT INTO mybranches (name,createdFrom,pulledFrom) VALUES (?,?,?)
```

Comment: give me 5 mins. i'll quickly try this.

Comment: No problem, take as long as you need :)

Comment: `pstmt.setDate(2,branch_created_on);` is giving me error: `incompatible types: LocalDateCannot be converted to Date`.  Because JavaFX `DatePicker` is `LocalDate`.

Comment: You have to use a `java-sql.Date` for this. (DEPRECATED, SEE NEXT COMMENT)

Comment: @Tanzeel: don't use `java.sql.Date` continue using `LocalDate`. You can use `pstmt.setObject(2, branch_created_on)` - at least if you are using an up-to-date driver

Comment: This is my final code: http://collabedit.com/7gbtd
But I'm getting a `NullPointerException`. Is this because of date format. Please check the link if possible.

Comment: This was enough to solve my problem. In fact I'm feeling more motivated towards Java now. :-)